# Indefinite Integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

We define Indefinite  integral of a function $f$ as $\int f(x)dx$ which is the collection of anti derivatives  of the function $f.$ But in many books it is written that for an integrable function $f$on $[a,b],$ $\int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx$ is the indefinite integral of $f.$ What is the difference between the two? Even we know that $\int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx$ may not be an anti derivative of $f$ for counterexample we may take $f$ as the thomae function on $[a,b]$. Then $\int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx=0 $ and so $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx=0$ $\neq f(x).$ Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thomae's function is not continuous.  So the FOC does not apply, does it?

Comment: But my question is about indefinite integral

Comment: An indefinite integral has no limits.  A definite integral does. Perhaps this is a point of confusion.  [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral)

Comment: But some books says $\int_{a}^{x} f$ as indefinite integral

Comment: Another thought is that not all anti-derivatives can be written as $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$.  Consider for example $f(x)=\cos x$.  The anti-derivatives of $f$ are $\sin x+C$ for all real numbers $C$.  But $\int_a^x \sin t\,dt=\sin x-\sin a$ and $\sin a$ is bounded by $1$.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $x\in[a,b]$, then $\int_a^x f(t)\, dt$ is an antiderivative of $f$, but not an indefinite integral. An indefinite integral is a collection of antiderivatives.

Comment: @user236182 Yes!  And as I stated in an earlier comment, not all antiderivatives can be expressed as $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$

Comment: There is a book of real analysis by Bartle which says $\int_{a}^{x} f$ as indefinite integral.

Comment: That's mainly a matter of convention. For ma, $\int_a^x f(x)\,\mathrm d x$ is the antiderivative of $f$ that vanishes at $a$.

Answer (score 3):

That's(definition of indefinite integral) just abuse of notation, nothing more. Those are two different concepts. Just make sure in what sense the author of talking.

The difference is, if indefinite integral exists in the first sense(in the order you kept them in your question) then indefinite integral will exist in the second sense, but if indefinite integral exists in the second sense then indefinite integral may not exist in the first sense(as your example tells us).

Comment: Its not the answer of my question

Comment: Please edit your answer so that it gives sufficient solution.

Comment: Edited. Is the answer okay now?

Comment: But why we say in both sense as indefinite integral if they are not equivalent.

Comment: This happens many times in mathematics, we use same notation for two distinct objects, same name for two distinct objects. That's the abuse of notation. 'Notation' may be same, but 'sense' is different in those cases. You've to know in what sense the author is talking. Is it clear now??

Comment: Ok thanks ...i am confused about it...